# Get HTML from database into React

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I have the following JSON from my test API:

```
{
    "/page-one": "<div><h1 className='subpage'>Database page one!</h1><p className='subpage'>Showing possibility of page one</p><p className='subpage'>More text</p></div>",
    "/page-two": "<div><h1 className='subpage'>Database page two!</h1><p className='subpage'>Showing possibility of page two</p><p className='subpage'>More text</p></div>",
    "/page-two/hej": "<div><h1 className='subpage'>Database page two supbage hej!</h1><p className='subpage'>Showing possibility of page two with subpage</p><p className='subpage'>More text</p></div>"
}
```

I want do create a dynamig page that uses the URL pathname to determine which HTML should be used/displayed. I have tried the following:

```
import React from 'react';

import Utils from "../../utils";
import './not-found-controller.css';

class GenericController extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.getPage = this.getPage.bind(this);
    }

    async getPage() {
        const pageList = await Utils.http.get('http://demo5369936.mockable.io/pages');
        console.log(pageList.data);
        const possiblePages = Object.keys(pageList.data);

        if (possiblePages.indexOf(window.location.pathname) !== -1) {
            return pageList.data[window.location.pathname];
        } else {
            return (
                <div>
                    <h1 className="subpage">404 - Page not fpund!</h1>
                    <p className="subpage">The page you are looking for is not found. Please contact support if you thing this is wrong!</p>
                </div>
            );
        }
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <section className="not-found-controller">
                { this.getPage }
            </section>
        );
    }
}

export default GenericController;
```

But this does not work. I only get the following error:

```
Warning: Functions are not valid as a React child. This may happen if you return a Component instead of <Component /> from render. Or maybe you meant to call this function rather than return it.
    in section (at not-found-controller.js:31)
    in NotFoundController (at app.js:166)
    in Route (at app.js:164)
    in Switch (at app.js:88)
    in div (at app.js:87)
    in App (created by Route)
    in Route (created by withRouter(App))
    in withRouter(App) (at src/index.js:18)
    in Router (created by BrowserRouter)
    in BrowserRouter (at src/index.js:17)
```

The API call is correct, the `console.log(pageList.data);` prints the JSON correctly. I tried to search for how to include HTML like this but I did not find any answer that made me understand.

Comment: Try to add this.getPage() instead of this.getPage. Try to set it in state then render that state.

Comment: @jitesh I have aldeary tried both those approaches and neither worked.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

3 things wrong here, but your browser's console should've told you the errors already.

First, your `getPage` method is `async`, but React rendering passes should be synchronous and execute immediately with whatever data is present. If the data is not present, the component should still render (you can return `null` from render to render "nothing"). Instead, fetch your data outside of a render pass and call `setState` when the data is available.

Second, `getPage` is returning a HTML string, which is not going to be parsed this way, but rendered as-is. You need to use the [dangerouslySetInnerHTML](https://zhenyong.github.io/react/tips/dangerously-set-inner-html.html) prop.

Third, as [jitesh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1923626/jitesh) pointed out, you are missing the function call brackets.

All things considered, you need something like the following (just thrown this together real quick, but you should get the idea):

```
constructor(props, context) {
    super(props, context);
    this.state = {
        pageData: undefined
    };
}

componentDidMount() {
    this.getPage();
}

async getPage() {
    const pageList = await Utils.http.get('http://demo5369936.mockable.io/pages');

    this.setState({
        pageData: pageList.data[window.location.pathname]
    });
}

render() {
    if (this.state.pageData) {
        return (
            <section
                className="not-found-controller"
                dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: this.state.pageData }}
            />
        );
    } else {
        // Not found or still loading...
    }
}
```

Comment: 30 seconds D: Clap

Comment: @SLCH000 Close enough!

Answer (score 3):

1) Use state to put loaded data to render. Like `this.setState({pageHtml: pageList.data})`

2) Use `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` to render your own html https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml